# mvn exec:java command line not using java.library.path

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, jacob

I am trying to execute a program using the mvn exec:java command.

I put this in a batch file (I am running Windows 11):

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.fiscalassets.tax.PrintForm1098s -Dexec.args="application.properties.FiscalAssets" -Djava.library.path="C:\OneDrive\Dev\Jacob"
```

But, when I run the batch file, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project FAIntegration: An exception occurred while executing the Java class. no jacob-1.20-x64 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Cygwin\usr\local\bin;C:\Cygwin\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QBPOSSDKRuntime;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync;C:\Program Files\Maven\bin;C:\Users\neil\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;. -> [Help 1]
```

The command does not seem to be passing the java.library.path definition to the Java command.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Can you try moving `exec:java` to the end of the command?

Comment: That made no difference

Comment: First try that at the command line (not in the batch file) - what happens?

Comment: @g00se Same error, nothing changed

Comment: Well, let me ask the obvious: *is* the dll at that path?

Comment: Yes, it is. But, even so, the output does not even list it as part of the directories it is searching.

Comment: OneDrive can be problematic owing to not being a regular directory. Try your home directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is that `java.library.path` cannot be used this way with `java` goal.

Documentation [says](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#systemProperties) we should use `MAVEN_OPTS` instead:

```
MAVEN_OPTS='-Djava.library.path="C:\OneDrive\Dev\Jacob"' mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.fiscalassets.tax.PrintForm1098s -Dexec.args="application.properties.FiscalAssets"
```

Comment: Yes, I chose to use exec:exec, but MAVEN_OPTS would also work.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It turns out I had to change my command to use exec:exec and pass the arguments this way:

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="java" -Dexec.args="-Djava.library.path=C:\OneDrive\Dev\Jacob -cp %classpath com.fiscalassets.tax.PrintForm1098s application.properties.FiscalAssets"
```